# Magento migration SQL error

Tags: magento-1.9, migration

I am **trying to migrate a magento1 shop to magento2 on another server**. 
I did `install the migration tool` and `configure everything correctly`.
Here is an example of my `config.xml`:

```
<source>
            <database host="mymagento1.com" name="magento1db" user="magento1user" 
    password="mypassword"/>
            </source>
            <destination>
            <database host="localhost" name="magentodb2" user="magento2user" 
password="mypassword"/>
            </destination>
```

after executing this command:

```
php bin/magento migrate:settings --reset vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.7/config.xml
```

i get the following error:

```
[Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception]                                                                     
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'magento1user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

It **seems the migration tool is trying to connect to the Magento2 database with the magento1 user**. I also **tried with the magento2 server IP** instead of `localhost` but I get the same error. I **triple checked the DB credentials**, everything is correct... 
I found mutiple posts with the same issue but no solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magento migration tool cannot connect your magento 1 database. Try one thing. Import your Magento 1 database in you localhost and change the credentials in config.xml and try it again. Remember, no need to run --reset command, it works when you will try to re-migrate.

Comment: Let me know if this helps. Best of luck :-)

Comment: I imported the source DB on the new server, it now works :)

Comment: sounds great :)

Answer (score -1):

both of your databases are in different servers? Yes you are right, at the time of migration Magento tries to connect both of the databases,if it connects successfully then your Magento 1 settings and data will be migrated.

Comment: yes, different servers